# Direction of acceleration in special relativity

Tags: special-relativity

[image]

what is the consequences and possible interpretation of the fact one can find "that acceleration is not in the direction of force"

Comment: What are your thoughts on thought on this? Where have looked, for example : https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Four-acceleration

Comment: That’s vector notation, not tensor notation.

Comment: In relativity there are four-dimensional vectors called the four-acceleration and the four-force which *are* parallel. The lesson is that using 4D spacetime, not 3D space plus time, is the right way to understand nature.

Comment: Its true, but one can explain the above result in more fundamental way.

Comment: The second term prevents the object from accelerating to speeds beyond $c$.

Answer (score 1):

Remember that an object cannot have a constant acceleration forever in special relativity, because the more the speed gets closer to c, the less effective a force will be in changing its speed (an object cannot have a constant acceleration forever in special relativity because that would eventually make its speed exceed c, thanks to @GSmith for the clearer comment). The equation above includes this phenomena. Imagine your force decomposed into components parallel and perpendicular to the velocity. The perpendicular component of the acceleration is the same as the classical one, because the speed is zero in that direction. But the component of the acceleration in the direction of the velocity has a correction that makes it smaller, to take into account the fact that a given force is less effective in changing the speed the larger the speed is.

Comment: But the text of the book uses word" in general" acceleration is not parallel but their is acceleration. Focus on that "there is acceleration "

Comment: I am sorry but I do not understand what you want to say

Comment: An object *can* have a constant proper acceleration forever in SR. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbolic_motion_(relativity)

Comment: @G.Smith in the question is the regular acceleration dv/dt, not dv/dtau

Comment: It seems to me that it would be clearer to say “an object cannot have a constant acceleration forever in special relativity because that would eventually make its speed exceed $c$” rather than talking about the force getting “less effective”.

Comment: But that’s a quibble. I’ve upvoted.

Comment: @G.Smith I agree with you, thanks for making it clearer

Comment: I was under the impression that acceleration in SR referred to change of rapidity instead of velocity, just so that it could be kept collinear with the force? Or was that GR only?

Answer (score 0):

Suppose a ship with a velocity **U** to an inertial frame of reference. The force term relates to the acceleration as measured by the crew of the ship. If someone drops an object inside the ship, it falls according to $a = F/m$. $F$ is also the force that can be felt inside the ship, as an artificial gravity. It can be constant for example for the time that there is fuel to burn.

For the inertial observer, the acceleration is not the same, and in general has a different direction. That acceleration is the real increment of the ship velocity with time, according to (the inertial frame) coordinates. If it were constant the calculated velocity would be unbounded.

Answer (score -1):

When you sit on an airplane and eat a pea, the pea is converted to fat, and the momentum that the pea had is inherited by your body.

The force that eating a pea causes is: F = delta p  / delta t

The consequence of that forwards pointing force is that the seat does not need to exert a forwards pointing force on your body when you sit and eat on a airplane seat.

Now if you bounce up from the seat using the previously gained fat as energy source, the momentum that the fat has is inherited by the rest of your body. Every cell of your body gains a bit forwards pointing momentum, which means that there is a forwards pointing force.

If the speed of the airplane is close to c, then the force that a person bouncing up from his set generates, points almost straight to the forwards direction, which of course has an effect on how fast that person is rising upwards. An observer  standing on the ground may say that the upwards motion of the passenger is time dilated.

Now let us consider a situation where zero force causes a non-zero acceleration.

You are coasting on a bicycle, you pick an apple from a tree while passing said tree (you use your hand, which decelerates to the rest frame of the apple and then accelerates back to the rest frame of the bike)

The force is zero as your momentum does not change as we count the apple as a part of you. But your speed changes.

That may perhaps sound dumb, but the point is the momentum of energy, and the conservation of momentum when energy collides with an object.